# Java and El Capitan

Tags: java, macos

I have installed El Capitan on my Mac, and whenever the mac boots, this screen appears.

[image]

Note that this window appears  many times  while using the mac.

Also, I have installed the latest java version (8.51) installed from the java.com [page](http://java.com/en).

How do I fix this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As the error message says you need a JDK(=Java development kit). The URL you posted is the JRE (which used to be sufficient but in Java 7 onwards on OS X this is the web plugin only - for other OS I think it includes the java command line)

You need to go to the [JDK downloads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index-jsp-138363.html#javasejdk)

Comment: Yeah, I know that the message refers to Java Development Kit. On the previous OS X versions, I had never installed JDK and I had never had such problems. Anyway, I'll give it a try.

Comment: Then you need to work out what is calling java - which is a separate question - also you might have Apple's Java 6 on the old OS which even in JRE had /usr/bin/java as did all other non Oracle java

Answer (score 2):

It is worth to mention, Apple still providing [JDK6](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572) for this newest release (El Capitan), Apple recommend user to use the latest Java from java.com.

The "More Info..." will actually bring you to java.com to download the latest Java, this is the recommended Java. Some reason you might need JDK6 is mainly for legacy software support, as mentioned on the Apple KB page. For me, I install both JDK8 and JDK6, the font rendering and color have a visible differences in both of these version, at least in JetBrains' product. Here is screenshot taken from JetBrains issue tracker.

[image: comparison image]

Comment: Ah-  what do you try to tell us and is this a solution for the Question?

Comment: If I am not wrong, the "More Info..." will actually bring you to java.com to download the latest Java. In case you need the JDK6 for legacy software support, as mentioned on the Apple KB page. For me, I use both JDK8 and JDK6, the font rendering and color have a visible differences in both of these version, at least in JetBrains' product.

Comment: Okay then put this in your answer too 

Comment: I hope that the answer will not go out of the scope of this question

Answer (score 2):

Clicking on the More Info link did not help.  I downloaded Java from Java for OS X 2015-001 (Apple's version of "legacy" Java) and the problem is solved for me.  https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?locale=en_US

Answer (score 0):

The other problem in OS X 10.11 is the new rootless SIP protection which sometimes blocks installation of Java. If it doesn't install for some reason, [disabling SIP](http://machow2.com/java-for-mac-el-capitan/) should allow the installation to complete successfully.